Resize the panel and y axis text size equally in R using ggplot2
I have the following toy data frame and ggplot2 graph. I want the size of the panel and the size of the text in y axis to be equal, like splitting the view in half. In the end, the result will be rendered in pdf what is the reason that I want this kind of resizing and splitting if I can say freely.
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(purrr)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "there is an argument sort_prop_include_center that could be set up to TRUE in order to include half of the centered level when sorting data" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "Similarly, the argument totals_include_center allows you to include half of the centered level into the left and the right totals" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "Here is one possible option which uses reorder and an ifelse to reorder the variable mapped on y using the counts (aka the sum) of Strictly disagree " = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "and disagree answers. Under the hood ggstats::gglikert reshape the data to long where the question id's are stored in a column named .question and the answers in a column named .answer:" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "They used sampling data and create a data frame called df. I am using the same as given in the link. (the df not the df_dk). Ok, if i run in R the following code :" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "proportion of answers higher than the centered level. I want the plot to be sorted according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e. Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two lower categories. )" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# function to save retyping common arguments
anno <- partial(annotate, "text", x = -1, angle = 90, size = 5, fontface = "bold")

gglikert(df) +
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
                    1, 0
                  ),
                  FUN = sum, decreasing = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1.5, 5.5), linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey20") +
  anno(y = 1, label = "warning\nzone", color = "#A6611A") +
  anno(y = 3.5, label = "so-so", color = "black") +
  anno(y = 6, label = "no warning\nzone", color = "#018571") +
  labs(y = NULL)


How can I succeed it in R using ggplot2?
Edit: if it is possible to remove the lines in the background theme .To be totally blank

Not clear, do you mean to have the y axis to be in the centre of the output: left side is the y axis tick label text, right side is the plot?

@zx8754 yes exactly this one .

This will require a bit of manual tweaking depending on your output size/device, but it gives you fine grain control over the final figure with the figure taking up the entire plot space.
The gist is to manipulate the space taken up by the y-axis labels through the use of the y_label_wrap argument in gglikert()

y_label_wrap number of characters per line for y axis labels, see scales::label_wrap()

We then should tweak the legend because it was already getting clipped prior to our edits.
As per your question edit, we can use panel(panel.grid = element_blank()) to remove all gridlines.
As per your comment question, it sounds like you may be interested in the totals_hjust argument which I have now set at 0.5.

totals_hjust horizontal adjustment of totals labels on the x axis

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(purrr)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "there is an argument sort_prop_include_center that could be set up to TRUE in order to include half of the centered level when sorting data" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "Similarly, the argument totals_include_center allows you to include half of the centered level into the left and the right totals" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "Here is one possible option which uses reorder and an ifelse to reorder the variable mapped on y using the counts (aka the sum) of Strictly disagree " = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "and disagree answers. Under the hood ggstats::gglikert reshape the data to long where the question id's are stored in a column named .question and the answers in a column named .answer:" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "They used sampling data and create a data frame called df. I am using the same as given in the link. (the df not the df_dk). Ok, if i run in R the following code :" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "proportion of answers higher than the centered level. I want the plot to be sorted according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e. Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two lower categories. )" = sample(
      likert_levels,
      150,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
    )
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# function to save retyping common arguments
anno <-
  partial(
    annotate,
    "text",
    x = -1,
    angle = 90,
    size = 3,
    fontface = "bold"
  )

gg <- gglikert(
  df, 
  labels_size = 2, 
  y_label_wrap = 68,
  totals_hjust = 0.5
) +
  aes(y = reorder(
    .question,
    ifelse(.answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
           1, 0),
    FUN = sum,
    decreasing = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = c(1.5, 5.5),
    linetype = "dashed",
    colour = "grey20"
  ) +
  anno(y = 1,
       label = "warning\nzone",
       color = "#A6611A") +
  anno(y = 3.5,
       label = "so-so",
       color = "black") +
  anno(y = 6,
       label = "no warning\nzone",
       color = "#018571") +
  labs(y = NULL)

gg +
  theme(
    # set to "inside" to enable use of `legend.position.inside`
    legend.position = "inside",
    # move legend to the left and down a smidge
    legend.position.inside = c(0, -0.1), 
    # maintain horizontal direction
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    # remove gridlines
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    # add some margin to prevent clipping
    plot.margin = margin(
      t = 1,
      r = 1,
      b = 25,
      l = 1
    )
  )


Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.1.0

very nice solution.Thank a lot.I appreciate it.But when I render it to pdf the vertial values near to y axis i.e the values 19%,24%31%,43%,43%,60% they remain in the middle and must be in the very right side.How this ca be fixed on your solution ?

Not sure what you mean. When I render to pdf the figure looks just like the one posted in the answer. Perhaps you are interested in playing around with the totals_hjust argument? You might want to ask another question to get at this new issue, but I have set totals_hjust = 0.5 thinking that is what you were interested in.

One option would be to split the elements and add them back together in a 50/50 width-sharing output using patchwork:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstats)
library(purrr)
library(patchwork)

likert_levels <- c(
  "Strongly disagree",
  "Disagree",
  "Neither agree nor disagree",
  "Agree",
  "Strongly agree"
)

df <-
  tibble(
    "there is an argument sort_prop_include_center that could be set up to TRUE in order to include half of the centered level when sorting data" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE),
    "Similarly, the argument totals_include_center allows you to include half of the centered level into the left and the right totals" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 5:1),
    "Here is one possible option which uses reorder and an ifelse to reorder the variable mapped on y using the counts (aka the sum) of Strictly disagree " = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "and disagree answers. Under the hood ggstats::gglikert reshape the data to long where the question id's are stored in a column named .question and the answers in a column named .answer:" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = 1:5),
    "They used sampling data and create a data frame called df. I am using the same as given in the link. (the df not the df_dk). Ok, if i run in R the following code :" = sample(c(likert_levels, NA), 150, replace = TRUE),
    "proportion of answers higher than the centered level. I want the plot to be sorted according to very left proportions that are the combination (sum) of the two lower levels. (i.e. Respectively the percentages on the very right in the sum of the two lower categories. )" = sample(likert_levels, 150, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ factor(.x, levels = likert_levels)))

# function to save retyping common arguments
anno <- partial(annotate, "text", x = -1, angle = 90, size = 5, fontface = "bold")

g1 <- gglikert(df) +
  aes(y = reorder(.question,
                  ifelse(
                    .answer %in% c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree"),
                    1, 0
                  ),
                  FUN = sum, decreasing = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1.5, 5.5), linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey20") +
  anno(y = 1, label = "warning\nzone", color = "#A6611A") +
  anno(y = 3.5, label = "so-so", color = "black") +
  anno(y = 6, label = "no warning\nzone", color = "#018571") +
  labs(y = NULL)

tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))

y_axis <- ggpubr::as_ggplot(tmp$grobs[[5]])

y_axis + (
  g1 + theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
) + plot_layout(widths = c(1, 1))



very nice solution.Thank a lot.I appreciate it.But when I render it to pdf the vertial values near to y axis i.e the values 19%,24%31%,43%,43%,60% they remain in the middle and must be in the very right side.How this ca be fixed on your solution ?
